# Model fetch including model as attribute in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Here is the test code:

```
var Stat = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            power: 0,
            speed: 1
        }
    });

    var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: "Igor",
            surname: "Ola",
            stats: null 
        },

        urlRoot: "/cgi-bin/test.pl"
    });

    var player = null; 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        player = new Player();
        player.set("stats", new Stat());
        player.fetch({
            success: function() {
                var text = player.get("stats").get("power");
                console.log(text);
            }
        });
    });
```

What I expect is that backbone would update the player model and it's stats attribute, which itself is another model (Stat).

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to do it? The goal is to update such a model in one fetch.

The `player.get("stats")` returns just an object, not Stat Model instance.

Comment: `defautls` is that a typo in that Stat model?

Comment: @akoskm yes, it should be defaults. corrected